# Translating non-latin characters from a latin only system

Tags: php, translation, base64, non-latin

Apologies if this has already been answered previously...

We've got an online mail reader (php based) that currently substitutes "�" or the upright rectangle for non-latin based characters in a window where the message body is loaded via an iframe. The texts are generally stored base64 encoded, so my question is, are there online translation tools that I can send the base64 encoded string that will decode the string, translate it, and return the translation (either base64 or decoded makes no difference)?

Comment: What character set is your data in and what character set are you outputting it in?

Comment: @Pekka, sorry should have specified. Output in UTF-8, input can change.  Problem mainly arises in spam from countries with non-latin based characters (China). We're writing URL based rules for spam, but the rule authors can't denote whether the message is spam or not since they can't figure out what the email is trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
base64_encode(mb_convert_encoding(base64_decode($string), 'charset1', 'charset2'));
```

you'd have to fill in appropriate values for the two character sets. however, you should be storing/processing/ouputting everything using UTF-8, as it makes so many of these kinds of problems simply vanish.

Comment: "you should be storing/processing/ouputting everything using UTF-8" I tried telling them that too... but yeah, upper management >_<